# Getting Error Process unexpectedly exit in Android Studio Version 4.0

Tags: android, gradle

I am having Android Studio Version 4.0 and using gradle in gradle.project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am getting error Process Unexpectedly Exit.

Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Project-Structure->Project

Change Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.3.2 or the last stable version for you Let the Gradle Version to 5.1.1

Click Ok and sync